# Not able to make spring boot take limited parameters while calling API from UI to backend using @RequestParam

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

Hello all I am using React JS as UI.

Firstly Assume I have designed form from where I am getting below 14 values

```
file
isSameMail
Student_firstName
Student_lastName
Student_Email
Student_details1
Student_details2
Student_details3
Student_details4
Student_details5
Student_details6
Student_details7
Student_details8
Student_details9
```

I am passing above values of form in Springboot API(registerStudent) using @RequestParam to register a student calling API from UI like

```
 let data = new FormData();
                data.append('file', this.state.file);
                data.append('isSameMail', false);
                data.append('Student_firstName', fields.firstName);
                data.append('Student_lastName', fields.lastName);
                data.append('Student_Email', fields.email);
                data.append('Student_details1', fields.details1);
                data.append('Student_details2', fields.details2);
                data.append('Student_details3', fields.details3);
                data.append('Student_details4', fields.details4);
                data.append('Student_details5', fields.details5);
                data.append('Student_details6', fields.details6);
                data.append('Student_details7', fields.details7);
                data.append('Student_details8', fields.details8);
                data.append('Student_details9', fields.details9);
                const url = http://localhost:8084/student/registerStudent';

                fetch(url, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  body: data,
                })
                  .then(res => {
                    if (res.ok) {
                      return res.json();
                    }
                    throw new Error(res.status);
                  })
                  .then(res => {
                    })
```

I am using spring-boot to call APIs were I am taking all the above values from form UI and storing it in the database(MYSQL)

Assume I am calling controller with API

```
@CrossOrigin
 @PostMapping(path = "/student/registerStudent", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> registerStudent(@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile UploadRegistrationForm,
                                                  @RequestParam("isSameMail") boolean isSameMail, @RequestParam("Student_firstName") String firstName,
                                                  @RequestParam("Student_lastName") String lastName, @RequestParam("Student_Email") String email,
                                                  @RequestParam("Student_details1") String details1, @RequestParam("Student_details2") String details2,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details3", required = false) Double details3,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details4", required = false) Double details4,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details5", required = false) Double details5,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details6", required = false) Double details6,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details7", required = false) Date details7,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details8", required = false) Integer details8,
                                                  @RequestParam(value = "Student_details9", required = false) String details9) throws IOException {
}
```

Now as you can see there are many parameters in registerStudent() method , but as I don't want to have parameters more than 7 parameters what is the appropriate way to use @RequestParam other than defining RequestParam several times.

Note:  we are getting 1 multipart file.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, this may be the solution for you.

You can create an Object, which will contain all fields, and it will be look greate in controller method.

Something like this:

```
package com.example;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RegisterStudentReqestedParams {
    private MultipartFile UploadRegistrationForm;
    @NotNull
    private boolean isSameMail;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;
    @NotNull
    private String email;
    @NotNull
    private String details1;
    @NotNull
    private String details2;
    private Double details3;
    private Double details4;
    private Double details5;
    private Double details6;
    private Date details7;
    private Integer details8;
    private String details9;
}
```

And the controller now looks like this:

```
@CrossOrigin
    @PostMapping(path = "/student/registerStudent", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> registerStudent(@RequestBody @Valid RegisterStudentReqestedParams registerStudentReqestedParams){}
```

Comment: Hey hi, by following above approach it gives me an error ::Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryhRjitDH2YBTAO0DA;charset=UTF-8' not supported]

Comment: @ShraddhaAgarwal can you share the full code of controller?

Comment: you can try with `@ModelAttribute` instead of `@RequestBody`